# Put Image Beside Navbar Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Edit #1:  Here's a picture of the issue:

[image]

Edit #2: Here's a picture after I use the brand class

[image]

Edit #3:

[image]

I'm trying to float an image beside a navbar.  It works until I have the navbar 100% width.  Then the navbar goes below the image.

Here's my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img alt="Brand" class="pull-left" src="Images/logo.png">
          </a>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Android TV</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shaw Direct</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>  
    </div>
</nav>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.Navlinks {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.Navlinks:hover {
    color: white;
}
.Navlinks:focus {
    color: white;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #00AEFE;
    height: 89px;
}

.nav.navbar-nav li a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Is there a way to make sure these two can float side by side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example in official docs:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="...">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image

Comment: That seems to make it worth.  The logo is almost center of the navbar.

Comment: @ThomasHutton That's the way to do it. Did you keep your old css targeting the logo or remove it? I'd recommend removing it and styling the logo anew.

Comment: @ThomasHutton Looks good, is it rendering as you want it to? Maybe take a screenshot or set up a fiddle? I don't know how big your logo is.

Comment: Found the problem, take a look at my answer. @Serg Chernata you made a tiny mistake forgetting the `button` in `navbar-header`

Comment: @ThomasHutton I see the new image, that's fine, your logo is just huge. Size is down so that it fits better by either scaling the image itself or setting height / width.

Comment: @mohamadfaramarzi the button does not matter, this example is from official docs, it works as it is. The only remaining issue is that the logo image is too big at this time.

Comment: You're right @SergChernata, in this case button dosen't matter, but i found an issue in his edited code and i saw `button` outside of `navbar-header` instead of into it. so it will go wrong in mobile devices.

Comment: @SergChernata what size would it ideally be?  I resized it 300x89, and same issue.

Comment: @ThomasHutton what is the current issue? The last thing I was aware of was how big the logo was. Ideally you want it to be a little smaller in height than the height of navigation. If the nav is 90px tall, you want the logo to be about 70-80, etc.

Comment: I want the logo to be the height of the navbar, and the left of the navbar.  This has it in a different place, and has a small margin above it.

Comment: @ThomasHutton but the logo IS on the left side of the navbar. The margin is there because it is applied to containing element, if you want to get rid of it give your logo a negative top margin.

Comment: OK, it's close, but is it possible to get it all the way to the left side?

Comment: @ThomasHutton you can change container class to container-fluid, which will make the design more "full-screen", pulling logo to the left and navigation to the right. Traditionally design is based on a grid, if you inspect the html structure of your code in the browser you will see that the body of your design has a width and it is centered on screen. This is why the logo is as far left as it currently can be. It's meant to be that way.

Comment: @ThomasHutton if I've sufficiently helped you, I'd appreciate you accepting my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131740/discussion-between-thomas-hutton-and-serg-chernata).

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is based on @Serg Chernata answer**

Your logo must be transparent and if it's so bigger than what you want, maybe a css style `width` or `height` to `<img>` tag is needed. something like `navbar-brand > img {height: 40px;}`

also you should move `<button>` into `<div class="navbar-header">` to right positioning of navbar toggle button in mobile devices.

```css
.Navlinks {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.Navlinks:hover {
  color: white;
}
.Navlinks:focus {
  color: white;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #00AEFE;
  height: 89px;
}
.nav.navbar-nav li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" class="pull-left" src="Images/logo.png">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Internet</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Phone</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Android TV</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Shaw Direct</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I edited my answer, check it again and let me know if helps you.